# Should variable names have adjectives before or after the noun?

Tags: python, c++, naming-conventions

I find that I am often a little inconsistent in my naming conventions for variables, and I'm just wondering what people consider to be the best approach. The specific convention I am talking about is when a variable needs to be described by a noun and an adjective, and whether the adjective should come before or after the noun. The question is general across all programming languages, although personally I use C++ and Python.

For example, consider writing a GUI, which has two buttons; one on the right, and one on the left. I now need to create two variables to store them. One option would be to have the adjective before the noun, and call them `left_button`, and `right_button`. The other option would be to have the adjective after the noun, and call them `button_left`, and `button_right`. With the first case, it makes more sense when reading out loud, because in English you would always place the adjective before the noun. However, with the second case, it helps to structure the data semantically, because `button` reveals the most information about the variable, and `left` or `right` is supplementary information.

So what do you think? Should the adjective come **before** or **after** the noun? Or is it *entirely* subjective?

Comment: I am interested to hear what others have to say on this topic... FWIW, I tend to think that consistency is more important than a convention; the worst case would be a `left_button` next to a `button_right`...

Comment: Personally, I tend to use the adjective after the noun, e,g. `button_left`. If I then wanted to add an attribute of this, I would add this at the end, e.g. `button_left_width`. It sounds strange saying it out loud, but is more understandable when reading code.

Comment: @Karnivaurus I use also adjective after the noun because with inteli sense its easier to find correct one especially when they are many. By typing button u get filtered variable list and you can see which buttons you have declared. I'm using Qt-Creator.

Comment: Nice question, but unfortunately opinion-based.

Comment: Similar question, but in Software Engineering SE: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/347944/64166

Answer (score 8):

I try to use `noun_adj` because it conforms to what I use for functions. When I write functions I tend to use `verb_noun_adj`, for instance:

```
def get_button_id():
    """Get id property of button object."""
    pass
```

This reads to me a bit more clearly that `get_id_button` because it is not entirely clear what you are getting here: is it getting the button.id or is getting a button called 'id' or maybe even something else? Unless you expand the name to be a bit more clear, like `get_id_of_button` which may be a bit too verbose for you.

There's probably an equally valid argument against what I'm doing here, but at least I'm being consistent in my madness?

Comment: Madness? Did you mean Saneness? Upped you! ;)

Comment: You said an example of `verb_noun_adj` is `get_button_id`, but `get_button_id` is actually an example of `verb_adj_noun`. The noun isn't `button`, the noun is `id`. The function gets an `id`. What kind of `id`? This is described by the adjective, `button`. The function gets a `button` `id`. So an example of `verb_noun_adj` would actually be `get_id_button`, which is misleading. The function isn't getting a `button` object, it's getting the `id` property. This is why adjectives should come before nouns, as they do in English.

Comment: @KrzysztofCzelusniak I read it as "I'm getting a button, what of the button? the id". Maybe `get_car_color` would be a better example.

Comment: I disagree. You aren't getting a button, you're getting an id of a button. At the end of the day, it's an id, not a button.

It's the same thing with a car color. You aren't getting a car, you're getting a color. A color of a car. Color is the noun.

Answer (score 6):

I think that writing the adjective before the noun is the more common thing. But if you think about it for a second, writing it after the noun is easier when reading your code. The adjective can easily be seen as a attribute of the noun. In a logic way of thinking, this is the better way in my opinion.